# Want a zoomed-in display to pan the way a Mac does

Tags: display, pantheon, user-interface

One thing I would like to make more like MacOS is the way the display pans when you've zoomed in on it, using the "zoom in" shortcut Cmd-plus. On a Mac, the display pans (moves across the screen) only when the cursor hits the edge of the screen, whereas on eOS it pans continuously as you move the cursor, so you also reach the edge of the display once the cursor hits the edge of the screen. The latter has the unfortunate effect that your display is essentially always moving around, which I find quite distracting (wouldn't anyone?).

If there isn't an Xserver option to get this behavior, please regard changing this as a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Contact with the developer on github. 
https://github.com/elementary

Answer (score 0):

I also am looking for a solution but don't see one. It might be possible by modifying Pantheon. But you can try the program 'kmag' (apt install kmag) which creates a window which is zoomed in to your screen. It's not really the same. But you could move it to a second screen which would then be a zoomed in version of your main screen.